# Weird Integral Involving Hermite Polynomials

Tags: integration, fourier-series, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

I have stumbled upon the following integral involving the Hermite polynomials:

$$ I(m) = \int_\mathbb{R}  e^{i m x} \left[ e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} H_m(x) \right] dx \, , \quad m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \, , $$

which is rather weird. It came up from trying to obtain an expansion in terms of the harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions from a Fourier series.

I have searched in function manuals and also tried to solve it term by term to find a predictable series, but the coefficients don't make sense to me. Does it look recognizable? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here are closed expressions for the first six $m$ values:

\begin{align}
 I(0) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \\ 
 I(1) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( \frac{2i}{\sqrt{e}} \right) \\
 I(2) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( -\frac{14}{e^2} \right) \\
 I(3) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( -\frac{180 i}{e^\frac{9}{2}} \right) \\
 I(4) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( \frac{3340}{e^8} \right) \\
 I(5) &= \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( \frac{80600 i}{e^\frac{25}{2}} \right) 
\end{align}

There's obviously a rule of type $I(m) \propto \sqrt{2 \pi} e^{-m^2/2} i^m$, but the numerical coefficients follow some non-intuitive rule.

Comment: Do you know of closed forms for any small $m$? Also, I'm not terribly knowledgeable in this particular topic, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114701/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-h-kxe-x2-2-where-h-k-is-the-hermit?rq=1) looks like it could be useful.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut thanks for the interest. The link you provided is not very useful, since the Fourier transform is quite different from what I've shown in the equation (and is also present in any quantum mechanics book). Now, for any not huge $m$ I can give you the integral's result. It converges and is well behaved. Remember $m$ cannot be "small" since it is an integer.

Comment: Oh well - worth a try. By "small" $m$ I meant like $0,1,2,3$. Wolfram|Alpha doesn't give closed forms for any small positive integers.

Comment: That's weird. Mathematica gives me closed forms up to $m=10$...

Comment: Something must not be working right in the WA <-> Mathematica exchange. Would you mind posting a couple of those closed forms in the question?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer follows from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 7.376,
$$ I_n(y):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\,x\,y}e^{-x^2/2} \, H_n(x) \, dx = \sqrt{2 \pi} e^{-y^2/2}
H_n(y) i^n .$$
Just set $n=m$ and $y=m.$  I'd attempt a proof, but I need to what is allowed as a starting point.

EDIT

Formula above is easily derived from generating function
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} H_n(x) = \exp{(-t^2+2x\,t)} $$
Make a generating formula for $I_n(y),$ interchange integral and sum, and use the previous formula like so:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} I_n(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty
e^{i\,x\,y} e^{-x^2/2}  \exp{(-t^2+2x\,t)}dx = e^{-t^2} \exp{(\frac{1}{2}(2t+iy)^2 )}\sqrt{2\pi}$$
where the well-known Gaussian integral has been used in the last step.  Arrange the exponentials as follows:
$$e^{-t^2} \exp{(\frac{1}{2}(2t+iy)^2 )}= e^{-y^2/2} \exp{( -(it)^2 +2(it)y )} $$
Use the generating function again, but now the argument is $it.$  Equate coefficients of $t$ to complete the proof.

Comment: That's it, mate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By completing the square of the exponential terms it can be seen that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i m x} \, e^{-x^2/2} \, H_{m}(x) \, dx &= e^{-m^2/2} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-i m)^{2}/2} \, H_{m}(x) \, dx \\
&= e^{-m^2/2} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^{2}/2} \, H_{m}(u + i m) \, du
\end{align}

Now make use of 
$$H_{n}(x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, H_{k}(x) \, (2 y)^{n - k}$$
in the form
$$H_{m}(u + i m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \, H_{k}(i m) \, (2 u)^{m-k}.$$
This leads to:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i m x} \, e^{-x^2/2} \, H_{m}(x) \, dx &= \sqrt{2} \, e^{-m^2/2} \, \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} H_{k}(i m) \, 2^{3(m-k)/2} \, \Gamma\left(\frac{m-k+1}{2}\right). 
\end{align}
This series can be reduced, but is sufficient for some calculations.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the results don't match Mathematica's. I'll update the question with some closed expressions for a few values of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi_m = e^{-x^2/2} H_m(x)$. Applying the Fourier transform to $\psi_0$ and to the relation $\psi_{m + 1} = x \psi_m - \psi_m'$ gives
$$\hat \psi_0 = \sqrt {2 \pi} \,\psi_0, \\
\hat \psi_{m + 1} = i x \hat \psi_m - i \hat \psi {}_m', \\
\hat \psi_{m} = C_m \psi_m \supset \hat \psi_{m + 1} = i C_m \psi_{m + 1}, \\
\hat \psi_m = \sqrt {2 \pi} \,i^m \psi_m, \\
I(m) = \hat \psi_m(m).$$