# Computing a Fourier transform of $t \mapsto e^{t^2/2}\frac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{-t^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a real-valued function $h_k(t)$ defined by
$$
t \mapsto \exp\left(\,{t^{2} \over 2}\right)\,
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k}}{\mathrm{d}t^{k}}e^{-t^2}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad k \in \mathbb{N}_0.
$$
I need to show that
$$\mathcal{F}h_k = (-i)^k\sqrt{2\pi}h_k$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is a Fourier transform, i.e $\mathcal{F}: L^1(\mathbb{R}) \to L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by $f(x) \mapsto \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\ dx$. First, as a hint, I need to show that $h_{k+1}(t) = h^{\prime}_k(t) -th_k(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I manage to show this hint, but the problem is, how is this helpful. There is $h_{k+1}$ in the equation, but I only want $\mathcal{F}h_k$. The operator $\mathcal{F}$ is linear, so
$$\mathcal{F}h_{k+1} = \mathcal{F}h^{\prime}_k - \mathcal{F}(th_k).$$
I know that $\mathcal{F}h^{\prime}_k(x) = \widehat{h^{\prime}_k}(\xi) = i\xi\widehat{h_k}(\xi)$ and $-\mathcal{F}(th_k) = \widehat{-th_k}(\xi) = -i(\widehat{h_k})^{\prime}(\xi)$. So,
$$\widehat{h_{k+1}}(\xi) = i\xi\widehat{h_k}(\xi)-i(\widehat{h_k})^{\prime}(\xi).$$
I have no idea what to do next. If anyone has an idea, could you please share your idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't your definition be $$h_n(t) = e^{t^2/2} \frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{-t^2}$$

Comment: $e^{-t^2/2}$ should indeed be $e^{t^2/2}$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2951336).

Comment: I have edited the question. It should be indeed $e^{t^2/2}$

Answer (score 2):

First of all see how it works [with the generating function of the Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform)

Your exercice is saying that if $\hat{h} = ch$ then $\widehat{ h'-th} = it \hat{h}-i \hat{h}' = it c h- ich'$

Comment: "itch". Heh. This was an amusing proof.