# Proving Normalized Hermite Polynomials are the eigenfunctions of Fourier Transform by alternative definition without generating function

Tags: fourier-transform, hermite-polynomials

I am well aware of the existence of proofs like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804851/fourier-transform-of-hermite-polynomial-via-generating-function) showing that the normalized Hermite polynomials are the eigenfunctions of Fourier Transform, by manipulating the generating function. However, I am reading Stone and Goldbart Exercise 2.5, which wants the reader to prove this without generating function but instead just using the following definition
\begin{align*}
H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2}
\end{align*}
such that
\begin{align*}
\varphi_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!\sqrt{\pi}}} H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(\varphi_n) = \imath^n\varphi_n(x)
\end{align*}
where the Fourier transform is defined as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(f) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\imath xs} f(s) ds
\end{align*}
I tried to use integrating by parts but I can't proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See the comment by Jack d'Aurizio to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114701/305862)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, but it is not the way I am looking for…

Comment: I don't understand : this comment proposes a method which does not involve any generating function ! Using the differential equation verified by $H_n$ is one of the  (many) ways to define $H_n$...

Comment: @JeanMarie The book specifically requires us to start by using the definition I typed as the first equation in the post to do the proof… (Also in the book Hermite equation is not mentioned yet, although I know about it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative demonstration may use a proof by induction based on the recurrence relation $H_n(x) = xH_{n-1}(x) - H_{n-1}'(x)$, which itself implies $\varphi_n(x) = \frac{x\varphi_{n-1}(x) - \varphi_{n-1}'(x)}{\sqrt{2n}}$. However, we must be careful with the notation, because it can lead to an actual muddle in the present case.

For recall, we would like to prove that $\mathfrak{F}[\varphi_n(x)](k) = (\color{red}{-i})^n\varphi_n(k)$. The base case $n = 0$ is easily checked, since $\varphi_0$ is a gaussian, which is mapped to another gaussian in the Fourier space. Then we assume the wanted relation for $n-1$, so that the induction step gives :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathfrak{F}[\varphi_n(x)](k) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \mathfrak{F}\left[\frac{x\varphi_{n-1}(x) - \varphi_{n-1}'(x)}{\sqrt{2n}}\right](k) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\left(i\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}k}\mathfrak{F}[\varphi_{n-1}(x)](k) - ik\mathfrak{F}[\varphi_{n-1}(x)](k)\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2n}}\left(k(-i)^{n-1}\varphi_{n-1}(k) - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}k}(-i)^{n-1}\varphi_{n-1}(k)\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (-i)^n\frac{k\varphi_{n-1}(k) - \varphi_{n-1}'(k)}{\sqrt{2n}} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (-i)^n\varphi_n(k) 
\end{array}
$$