# About proper functions and Fourier transforms

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, proper-maps

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find examples of proper functions and their corresponding eigenvalues.

This question arises from the fact that $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is a well-known proper function or autofunction of the Fourier transform considered as an operator associated with the eigenvalue 1.

As a result, I would like to find other independent proper functions.

Thank you!

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114701/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-h-kxe-x2-2-where-h-k-is-the-hermit